# C# exception not being thrown/caught

Tags: c#, exception, dll, .net-assembly

I am trying to load dlls into my program at runtime that match a specific assembly attribute that I have set. In order to make sure that the dll is loadable before I check its flag I have written the following method:

```
private bool IsValidDll(string dll) {
        try {
            System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(dll);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) { return false; }
    }
```

I can loop through dlls in my current directory and call this method to see if it will be safe to load the dll and check its assembly attributes. However, I am hitting a dll that is not throwing/catching an Exception and is still just directly crashing the program. The relevant output window information is as follows:

```
LoaderException: System.IO.FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly is built against 
version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information. - Adapters.Spryware.SprywareAdapter
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

I have tried catching the specific Exception (System.IO.FileLoadException) but the catch block is still skipped over and I still crash. Any thoughts?

Also, I find that this is a pretty heavy handed way of checking for my assembly attribute. Is there a way to check for my flag without having to load the dll with Reflection first?

Comment: Try `ReflectionOnlyLoad` instead of `LoadFrom` to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: I think you are missing the DLL when you do the first check of IsValidDll...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I tried using ReflectionOnlyLoad and I now successfully throw the exception but every single dll throws an exception and returns false now where as before I was able to at least pull out the ones that I knew contained my Assembly Attribute.

Comment: @Danpe I am definitely not silly enough to have posted a question like this without verifying that first and if you had looked at the Output you would see that is definitely not the problem. Please try to make valid contributions.

Comment: Just guessing, but is it possible that the dll you are testing is actually fine (passes the above test) but one of it's dependancies is not and is crashing the app after being loaded?

Comment: Hard to explain.  If you are loading these assemblies in an AppDomain then be sure to show how you initialized it.

Comment: Where is the IsValidDll method being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to confess, I dont see why your code doesnt work either:

I made a .net 4 thing and ran and mine did catch it:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // foreach (String file in Directory.GetFiles("c:\\windows", "*.dll"))
        String file = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll";
        {
            try
            {
                //System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(file);
                System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                textBox1.Text += ee.Message + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
    }
```

On clicking the text box reads:
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Comment: Were you able to successfully load this dll or did it throw the exception? If so was was the value in textBox1.Text

Comment: It correctly threw the exception which was caught and message shown in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably solve this problem and be less heavy handed by loading the assemblies into the reflection-only context.

Basically, instead of fully loading the assembly, this gives you the ability to reflect over the assembly without the ability to do things like instantiate objects. This expressly allows you to look at assemblies that are built against different .NET framework versions than the one on which your application is running.

A thorough treatment is available on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172331.aspx